# Directive apply result to all directives instead of only one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I built this `directive` to controll some `affix` effect on the page

```
.directive('Affix', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.width = element.prop('offsetWidth');
            var elWidth = scope.width + 'px',
            elChild = angular.element(element[0].querySelector(':first-child'));
            elChild.css('width', elWidth);
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                var myElem = element[0];
                yPosition = 0;
                function getPosition(element) {
                    while(element) {
                        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
                        element = element.offsetParent;
                    }
                }
                getPosition(myElem);
                if (yPosition >= 0) {
                    elChild.removeClass('affix');
                } else if ( yPosition < 0) {
                    elChild.addClass('affix');
                };
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

It's working fine, except because when I'm using 2 or more elements on the page, the effect (or in this case, the class) is being applied to all of the directives on the page. Even if i use different directives names, for example: `affix-me` and `affix-zero`, the result is the same.

### Why I'm using 2 directives?

I need to do this because of the way it works. It's applying a class to the element when it's supposed to affix on the page, so the class `affix` with `position: fixed, top:0` is being applied. But in this case, i have one element that needs to be at a 25px distance from the top.

### What i noticed

Assuming I'm using 2 directives, example `affixMe` and `affixOther`.

Where `affixMe`has this code:

```
if (yPosition >= 0) {
    elChild.removeClass('affix');
} else if ( yPosition < 0) {
    elChild.addClass('affix');
};
```

And `affixOther`has this code:

```
if (yPosition >= 24) {
    elChild.removeClass('affixOther');
} else if ( yPosition < 24) {
    elChild.addClass('affixOther');
};
```

With some `console.log` i noticed the yPosition is being called correct until the point where the first element reachs the top.

Example:

- Elem.A: yPosition = 150;
- Elem.B: yPosition = 270;

When `Elem.A` is `yPosition = 0`; `Elem.B` was supposed to have `yPosition = 120`. But it goes from 121 to 0.

Does anyne have any idea on how to solve this?
Ps.: I want to keep it pure AngularJs/JS. No Jquery.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you created some simple jsfiddle or plunker. One thing that seems strange is - why use 2 directives when you can simply add a parameter and use it to distinguish between different elements (class name or height to fix, for example)?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Well.. I'm new to Angularjs.. So I built this based on a lot of research I did. If you know a better way to achieve the result, it's ok. I'm working like this, because this is how i managed to get it working. If there is an automatic way to apply the fix position direct to the element, or other improvemen, please feel free to manipulate the code how you want it. I'll be doing a fiddle.